# Could I just replace the RPC URL of Infura with the RPC URL on MetaMask of a different chain?

Tags: evm, infura, rpc, quicknode, endpoint

I have a backend code that uses the endpoint of Infura for Goerli. But I'm now working on a very new EVM that is not supported by any Web3 provider. So, could I just replace the RPC URL in my code with the one from MetaMask RPC URL? The one that I'm using to connect to the EVM to get test tokens.